# Sublime Text no longer launches from terminal

Tags: terminal, editor, osx-mavericks, sublimetext, sublimetext3

After upgrading ST3 to build 3065 I'm no longer able to launch it via the terminal:

```
[11:53:31] ❯ /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl .
Unable to launch Sublime Text
```

I've shown the absolute path just so nobody thinks it's a symlink issue.

The previous version of ST3 (build 3059, IIRC) did not have this issue.

`subl -h` works as expected and prints the help properly. Really, all the cli flags work except opening files. Explicitly providing a single file argument gives the same result.

Comment: You can try: http://www.uninstallonmac.com/?s=sublime

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Removing the following did the trick (not sure if it was *specifically* one of these, so listing all):

> ~/Library/Caches/com.sublimetext.3
>
> ~/Library/Preferences/com.sublimetext.3.plist

And then restarting ST3. Why they maintained a link to the old app, I cannot say.

Thanks to @Paul R. for helping to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 12):

I ran into this error and it turns out that the culprit was tmux (cf. [Can't open sublime text in tmux after upgrading to Yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26486345/682613)). So if you are trying to launch Sublime Text while in tmux and are receiving a "Unable to launch Sublime Text" then the culprit is a bug in tmux. (Cf. https://superuser.com/a/833791)

To repeat what the link above says:

> The issue is that tmux is changing the bootstrap to system domain when it shouldn't (see https://trac.macports.org/ticket/18357). Older versions of launchd worked around this bug in tmux, but the rewritten launchd in OS X Yosemite does not work around this tmux bug.
>
> You will either need to wait for Apple to possibly release an update that works around the tmux bug or pester tmux developers to fix this bug in tmux that has been known for at least 6 years now.

Comment: If you get this far, [see this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34916516/564181), which *resolves* the issue with tmux (though the tmux issue itself remains unresolved).

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get this working by running

```
# brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

and then aliasing the subl command in my `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc` as such:

```
alias subl='reattach-to-user-namespace subl'
```

Comment: P.S. - If you use Sublime as your default terminal editor you can place `export EDITOR="reattach-to-user-namespace subl"` in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually better to use `open` for this kind of thing:

```
open -a "Sublime Text" .
```

Comment: Hmm. Where does `open` maintain app links? In a plist, I assume? It seems `open` is referencing a previous version of ST that no longer exists.

Comment: What did you do with the old version ? Is it still in the trash ?

Comment: Negative, Ghost Rider. It's long gone.

Comment: Hmm - sounds like something is broken then - maybe run Disk Utility and repair permissions and/or reinstall ST ?

Comment: "It's usually better", it would be very beneficial to everyone if you could elaborate. Thank you!

Comment: @CarlesAlcolea: well, using `open` is a higher level of abstraction than just trying to directly execute the application's binary, and it takes care of various minor details for you. It also gives you a lot more flexibility as to how the application is launched (see `man open`). In most cases I expect either method would work, but there may be some cases where `open` does the right thing and the brute force method fails.

Comment: See, I learned something interesting. Knowing that, I think I'll create an alias using `open`!