# Can't open sublime text in tmux after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: macos, terminal, sublimetext, osx-yosemite

On my Mac OS Yosemite, I can open a terminal and run `subl` and it opens Sublime Text. But, if I start a `tmux` session and run `subl`, I get the error:

```
Unable to launch Sublime Text
```

If I try:

```
open -a "Sublime Text"
```

I get the error:

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application /Applications/Sublime Text.app with error -10810.
```

Comment: Not really a programming question. You'll probably have better luck on superuser or askdifferent.

Comment: Not a question for stackoverflow. Nevertheless I arrived here because I have the same problem :)

Comment: I agree.  I should have asked it somewhere else. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for the same problem over in superuser. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a solution to the problem at the moment. The link to the answer is

https://superuser.com/questions/831028/lsopenurlswithrole-failes-with-error-10810-on-yosemite-from-within-tmux/833791#833791

This is a huge issue, since Sublime isn't the only thing I open while in tmux.